# 500 internal server error for large JSON object

Tags: json

I have a website that displays a list of data from a database. I noticed the browser reporting a 500 Internal Server Error, but only in one case. Here's the controller method.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult GetTouches(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            List<p_SiteTouchSummary> pSiteTouchSummarys = ptsRepository.GetPSiteTouchSummarys().ToList();

            return Json(new { wasSuccess = true, pSiteTouchSummarys });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, Request.Path, UserHelper.GetEmployeeLogin());
            return Json(new { wasSuccess = false, message = "Error - Search failed" });
        }
    }
```

In debugging I found that it would reach the return, exist the method, and then never return to the javascript file that called it. The browser only takes about 1 second to report the 500 error, and it's not consistent, so I don't think it's a timeout.

Also, I modified the returned list with Take statements, and it works at 150, but not at 200. And if I do a Skip(150).Take(50) that also works. It seems to be that ~200 entries is somehow breaking it, but it's not reporting it being too big to deserialize.

Anyone know what is going on and a good way to fix it?

Comment: check the server's error logs for details about the 500. might be out of memory, maybe it's exceeding max runtime.... can't tell until you look.

Answer (score 1):

The JsonResult class does have a property(maxJsonLength),  try changing it:

```
    var jsonResult = Json(dataModel,
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.maxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
```

or

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Status 500 = "Internal Server Error". Which is a catchall error for anything where the server should give you a reasonable reply but doesn't. For example, if your server code throws an exception that isn't handle otherwise, the server will likely handle it by returning status 500 to the caller.

Solution: 1. Complain to the people responsible for the server code. 2. The server people might be able to tell you exactly what triggers the error, so you avoid it. 3. They might not give you anything useful, so you change your requests in a way that you believe guarantees no status 500 error, and if you still get one then repeat the request requesting fewer data.